# Android Emulator (API 10) Camera Not Working - ADT Bundle Linux

Tags: camera, linux, android-emulator, front-camera

The Camera on my Android API 10 Virtual Device isn't working. While creating the AVD there are three options I found for Back Camera:

1. None

   Webcam0

   Emulated

I tried all options 1, 2 and 3 to no avail. Also, Front Camera is set to `None` and selection is disabled. What is it that must be done for the emulator camera to work? Will any Camera app solve my problem? Can I have the Front Camera enabled somehow?

What it shows - no matter which option of the above I select - is a white screen with two icons near the bottom edge of the screen. One icon is for setting picture quality and/or restore default settings. The other icon is to enable/disable "store location" See the image below

[image]

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: which API are you targeting?

Comment: Was user35929 removed? It's just user35929 without hyperlink against his/her comment above! I searched for the user to not find him/her!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select version >= 4.0 and it will support the camera.

Comment: What version are you referring to?